# divide by zero - c programming

Tags: c, floating-point, nan

I have a question about the next code:

```
int main { 
double x = 0;
double y = 0/x;

if(y==1) {.....}
....
....
return 0;
}
```

When I run the code on my computer, I get no runtime error and I see that `y = -nan(0x8000000000000)`. Why it is not a runtime error to divide by zero?

Additionally, when I change the first line to `int x = 0;`
now there is a runtime error. What is the difference?

Comment: @Jens: No, annex F of the C99 standard overrides this and you don't get undefined behavior for floating point.  Not all implementations support annex F, but yours and mine do.

Answer (score 14):

You can't rely on this "working" (i.e. doing the same thing all the time, portably) at all, it's undefined behavior in C for the second case, and also for the first if your implementation doesn't define `__STDC_IEC_559__` (this is, I believe, rare these days).

C99, §6.5.5/5

> The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the
>   second; the result of the % operator is the remainder. **In both operations, if the value of
>   the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined.**

The fact you're getting a "Not a Number" in one case and and not in the other is that one is done in floating-point arithmetic, where, on your implementation (conforming to IEEE 754 division by zero semantics), `0/0` gives a NaN.

In the second case, you're using integer arithmetic – undefined behavior, there's no predicting what will happen.

Comment: It should be added that the observed behaviour is defined by the platform. Ix86 happens to implement division by zero this way.

Comment: This is actually wrong for most systems: C99, §F.1: "An implementation that defines `__STDC_IEC_559__` shall conform to the specifications in this annex.  Where a binding between the C language and IEC 60559 is indicated, the IEC60559-specified behavior is adopted by reference, unless stated otherwise."  §F.3 "The `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` operators provide the IEC 60559 add, subtract, multiply, and divide operations."

Answer (score 10):

The reason you don't get an exception or error is because for a double, infinity and NaN are defined (see [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008#Operations)) but when you try the same for integer, you'll get an error because NaN/Infinity aren't defined

Comment: You won't always get an error for integer `0/0`, it depends on the implementation.

Comment: but I only change the x value and not the y value.   So it is like saying as before . no ?

Comment: @JanHudec No, the compiler can also make optimizations on the fact, that `n/0` is UB. The compiler may remove this `if`-block `n=a/b; if(!b) {/*This code will be removed*/}`.

Answer (score 4):

This is because [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard defines special values for positive and negative infinity along with "not a number" for floating-point values.

Non-floating point types like `int` do not have those special values defined and so the run-time is being terminated due to un-handled error.

This is not C-specific, you will see a very similar (if not the same) behavior in other languages simply because this functionality is down to hardware.