# No Runtime error after divison by zero

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, runtime-error, runtimeexception

I am using Microsoft visual C++ 2010
and I have the following code in which I divide 1 by zero as you see

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{   
   int x;
   x = 0;
   1/x;

   while (1) {
      std::printf("RUNNING!!\n");
   }
}
```

and surprisingly I don't find any run time error and the program continued to execute and displays RUNNING!!

So my question why "1/x" is not considered a run time error , and why the program don't stop?

Comment: @haccks: No, I don't think that [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110825/divide-by-zero-c-programming) is a duplicate. The operands are of crucially different types, even! And the cause this time is different...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit; Not and exact dupe but "very close".

Comment: @haccks: But not close enough, seeing as both the question code and the answer are fundamentally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In complement to everybody else, I notice some comments about "getting or not a run-time error" that makes me thinking a misunderstanding of ambiguous terminology.

In common computer science a "runtime error" is no more that what the computer language of human brains (plain English) means: and error that is noticed during "program execution".

So yes, getting a dump from the OS after a signal is a "runtime error". At least for the English language.

But this has noting to do with `std::runtime_error` that is the `std::exception` that is thrown by the standard library (or whatever other code based on the standard library)  when an error is fund *in their own code*.

Also the term "exception" is ambiguous: in OS terminology it is the "rescue code" an appropriate OS driver put in answer to a CPU hardware trap.  In C++ is is either a base class representing all standard library errors OR whatever value subject of a throw statement.

The point, here, is that an integer division by zero is **not** a standard library implementation detected error: basic integer arithmetic is considered by the C++ language as primitive to the hosting environment. In most of the platforms, `operator/(int,int)` is implemented through a DIV  assembler instruction (at least on most of the CPU) and a DIV  with a 0 operand is handled by the CPU microcode as CPU exception, that produce a "trap" (or interrupt, or whatever the platform terminology calls it) handled by the OS (or a specific OS driver). There is nothing in the C++ compiler (and produced executable) that knows what's going on during the DIV evaluation (since it is internal to the CPU),so there is no **throw** statement that can be written, and hence no std::exception (or whatever other C++ type) to catch. Just an operating system driver that can be replaced, and that -by default- terminates the application.

That's a very similar behavior of the equivalent default `catch(...)` in the C++ startup code that invokes main (that calls exit), hence another source of confusion.

To complicate much more things, compiler optimization can discard whatever operation is not producing a used result, making everything to become even not visible.

So, output the division result is a must to let the compiler not discard the operation(s).  And when that is done, a CPU trap producing an OS signal is observed. This is -in plain English an "error at run-time", but is not a C++ `std::runtime_error` since no such a throw statement exist in the division operator implementation.

Answer (score 7):

Conversely, why do you think there *should* be a runtime error? There's no rule to mandate that.

It's *undefined* to divide by zero. In this case it seems like, because it could be caught at compile-time, your compiler simply ignored the operation … most likely because you never used its "result".

So, this program runs and possibly outputs nothing:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    1/x;
}
```

Whereas I could expect *this* program to result in a system-level arithmetic exception:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1/x;

    std::cout << y << '\n';
}
```

In general, when you have undefined behaviour, don't expect anything. Don't expect your program to "work", don't expect it to produce meaningful output, don't expect it not to phone your ex-wife and rescind legal custody of your pet chickens, and don't expect it to cause the error you wanted.

Comment: So , In the case of using its result , I have tried it and the program stops with a message saying  unhandled exception , Is this considered "run time error " or something else?

Comment: Thanks Lightness, I was wondering where my chickens went, and oops of course, I had divided by zero in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't assign the evaluation of `1/x` to another variable. That's why you didn't get the Runtime error.

If you modify your code like this -

```
int r;
r = 1/x;
```

Then the program stopped with an error.

Comment: You may still need to _use_ `r`.

Comment: I have just run the program in ubuntu 12.04 with gcc version 4.6.3. It gives me error without further using of `r` and the error is - `Floating point exception (core dumped)`. But I thought it would be runtime exception.

Comment: In what way is a SIGFPE and core dump _not_ a runtime error? What else did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

From the notes

> Stroustrup says, in "The Design and Evolution of C++" (Addison Wesley,
>   1994), "low-level events, such as arithmetic overflows and divide by
>   zero, are assumed to be handled by a dedicated lower-level mechanism
>   rather than by exceptions. This enables C++ to match the behaviour of
>   other languages when it comes to arithmetic. It also avoids the
>   problems that occur on heavily pipelined architectures where events
>   such as divide by zero are asynchronous."`

---

> So my question why "1/x" is not considered a run time error

You are not assigning the value of 1/x to any variable and hence you are getting any runtime error. Assign it to a variable and you will get a run time error.

Comment: This only explains why dividing by zero does not result in a C++-level exception, and partially at that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:- Yes as that was the only part which was missing, probably the correct answer ;)